# Convert an existing img to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an elegant way to convert an existing `<img>` on the document to base64 loaded `<img>`. So simply the src url will be converted to base64 data.

What's the best way to obtain this?

Comment: draw the image on a canvas, use canvas.toDataURL()

Comment: Do you really want to do that on the client side (as your tags indicate)? Why?

Comment: only to hide the image url from the average user

Comment: you can still right-click, Save Image As...

Comment: @dandavis i know, this is only to hide the url.

Comment: @dandavis also I am getting a "Tainted canvases may not be exported." error.

Comment: you can only convert images you serve or control the serving of using CORS http headers

Comment: hmm I see. So this won't work? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/31c074397e3b879e9da3

Comment: Is there any way to realize what I need?

Comment: this jsfiddle has a nice demo http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/

Comment: Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsiffle.net including `img` with `src` attempting to convert to `base64` ?

Comment: @Zettam: You cannot "hide urls" on the web. The user would just need to press `Ctrl`+`U` to view the source, and have access to all your urls. Even average users can do this nowadays.

Comment: @Bergi i know, jsut take this as a personal challenge.

Comment: @AmrMorsy here is an edited version of that http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJpGdm which works okay, but does not load "gif's" in an animated manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get image data in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make this work! (I got the same issue.) In the code below, `img` is the image DOM element:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

The line `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";` [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596576/failed-crossorigin-access-for-canvas-todataurl) to bypass CORS somehow, although I'm not sure if that's a "hack" and may be "fixed" at some point as I don't fully understand the issue with CORS here.